# I want to add a text in a cell if a number is below or above a value

Tags: cells

*emphasized text*

i want to add the text 'FULL Delivery'' or ''Not Full'' to a cell that is either below 48 or equal to 48.

can anyone help me.

Comment: `=if(A1<49;"Not Full";"FULL Delivery")` But keep in mind, you cannot use a formula to alter the same cell. So you have to put the number in A1, and the formula that displays the text into a different cell, such as A2 or B1.

Comment: Thank you!!, if i wanted to assign a different color to each statement, red for 'full deliver'' and green for '' not full'', is this possible?

Comment: Yes, using conditional formatting

Comment: Thank you so much, made my day.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add the text 'FULL Delivery'' or ''Not Full'' to a cell that is either below 48 or equal to 48.

`=if(A1<49;"Not Full";"FULL Delivery")`

But keep in mind, you cannot use a formula to alter the same cell. So you have to put the number in A1, and the formula that displays the text into a different cell, such as A2 or B1.

Optionally, you can use Conditional Formatting to change its colors.